# Create database if not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I want to create database if its not exist. I am using `sqlite` as a database source and `Entity Framework`. At first I added new model (code first) and set database source as `database.db` in current directory.

Next, I've added simple class:

```
class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And of course database context:

```
class TestContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public TestContext() :base("TestModel"){
        //Create database always, even If exists
        Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>());
    }
}
```

I've already had `connectionString` in `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestModel" connectionString="data source=&quot;C:\Users\root\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\dbTEST\dbTEST\bin\Debug\database.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And for some reason after running this piece of code:

```
using (var ctx = new TextContext()) {
    ctx.Database.Create();
}
```

I am getting error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Database 'main' cannot be created because it already exists.
```

I cant understand what's wrong with this. I dont know where `main` database comes from. I set database file as `database.db`. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Are you trying to do in Ef core or entity framework 6 ??

Comment: I have the same issue. Even if i override InitializeDatabase and do a manual Database.Create() when I know it does not exists. @Dawvawd: did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor dictates that the DB will be dropped and created each time the application starts.

Therefore remove ctx.Database.Create() as this is handled by the framework.